# Solving Functional Equation Involving Integration

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function such that $$f(x)=\frac{1}{t}\int^t_0 f(x+y)-f(y)dy$$ for all $x$ and all $t>0$. Prove that $f(x+z)=f(x)+f(z)$ for every $x$ and $z$.
$$$$From the given above relation we get $$f(x+z)=\frac{1}{t}\int^t_0f(x+y+z)-f(y)dy=\frac{1}{t}\int^t_0f(x+y+z)-f(x+y)+f(x+y)-f(y)dy=\frac{1}{t}\int^t_0f(x+y+z)-f(x+y)dy+\frac{1}{t}\int^t_0f(x+y)-f(y)dy$$ If we put $x+y=u$ the we get from the above result $f(x+z)=f(z)+f(x)$ for every $z$ and $x$
$$$$ Is the Proof Correct?

Comment: I don't think the proof is quite correct because when you substitute $u = x+y$ you will change the bounds of integration, so $$\int^t_0 (f(x+y+z) - f(x+y)) dy = \int^{t+x}_{x} (f(u+z) - f(u))du.$$ I think you just want to use the fundamental theorem of calculus here, which says that for a continuous function $g$, we have $$\lim_{t\to 0 } \frac 1 t \int^t_0 g(y)dy = g(t).$$

Comment: What is there in the first integral $dx$ or $dy$

Answer (score 1):

As User8128 pointed out, the change of variables changed the interval of integration. I suggest to apply directly the fundamental theorem of Calculus. For example,  one can write
$$ t f(x) = \int^t_0 f(x+y)-f(y)\,dy
$$
Since the integrand is continuous for any fixed $x$,  you can differentiate w.r.t $t$ to get

$$
f(x) = f(x+t) -f(t)
$$